# openshift spring boot logback pod specific log file

Tags: spring-boot, logging, kubernetes, openshift, logback

I am trying to configure pod specific log files for a spring boot deployment in openshift (v3.11). I am using logback for logging. Currently the log file name is configured in logback.xml at the configMap attached to the deployment and hence all pods of this, write to the same log file. Is there a way to do pod specific logging?

I tried to use env variables ${PID} ${POD_ID} $(id} in the below manner, but the log file created would be like application_log_POD-POD_ID_IS_UNDEFINED.log

Regards,
Seeni

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this in your logback.xml

```
<fileNamePattern>${instance.log.dir}/%d{yyyy-MM}/${POD_NAME}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log
          </fileNamePattern>
```

But you need to define the `POD_NAME` in the OpenShift environment variables.
For local I usually use something like this

```
<if condition='property("stage").matches("local")'>
        <then>
          <fileNamePattern>${instance.log.dir}/%d{yyyy-MM}/myApp.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log
          </fileNamePattern>
        </then>
        <else>
          <fileNamePattern>${instance.log.dir}/%d{yyyy-MM}/${POD_NAME}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log
          </fileNamePattern>
        </else>
      </if>
```

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes creates variable "hostname" for this. Not necessary to create any variable explicitly
Try :

```
  <fileNamePattern>${instance.log.dir}/%d{yyyy-MM}/${hostname}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log
      </fileNamePattern>
```

or

```
   <if condition='property("stage").matches("local")'>
    <then>
      <fileNamePattern>${instance.log.dir}/%d{yyyy-MM}/myApp.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log
      </fileNamePattern>
    </then>
    <else>
      <fileNamePattern>${instance.log.dir}/%d{yyyy-MM}/${hostname}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log
      </fileNamePattern>
    </else>
  </if>
```